# Trying to fix error code 7 with AlmaLinux 9 PHP 8.1 cURL?

Tags: php, php-curl

I recently installed AlmaLinux 9 with LAMP and everything works correctly except cURL. I have verified cURL is installed and enabled. When I run the following code I receive

```
$url = 'http://example.com/TellMeSomething';                      

$cURL = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$responseCode = curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$data = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);

if (!$data) {
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($cURL) . '" - Code: "' . curl_errno($cURL) . '" - HTTP_CODE: "' . $responseCode . '"');
} else {
    echo 'Success!!!';
}
```

This script returns Success on PHP 7, but returns Error: "" - Code: "7" - HTTP_CODE: "0" using PHP 8.1

I have verified the PHP installation has cURL enabled

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Error code 7 is `CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7) - Failed to connect() to host or proxy.`

Comment: Can you call `curl_getinfo` before `curl_exec`?  I don't know the answer to this but it seems strange to want the status code of a request you haven't made yet.

Comment: aynber - Thank you but I know what the error message means, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: apokryfos - I have changed the location of the curl_getinfo with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. I ran the following command on the server.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```